# Distribute iOS App executable ( iPA ) to a set of users over email to install

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I recently finished an application in Unity for a client who runs a sporting event and wanted the app to let the referees keep a more accurate log of the statistics of each game. When building for android, i get a single file that i can send to my device and install it/run it. The part that i have some questions is re-building that same project for IOS.

I know i MUST have xcode which means i MUST have a mac OS, but here are a few questions that i am unaware of.

1) With the most recent release of xcode, developers dont need the $99 apple developers kit to produce something and test it on their device. From what i learned, is it true that you need to verify each device you send the application to in order to test it?

2) Is there a way to compile the IOS application in a way that i can get a single file, or even a folder, and send it via email to my client, at which point they can download the file to their phone and have the application installed?

3) What is the easiest route i can take in order to get my application into ~30 peoples iphones without individually signing each phone to my application?

Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove this question as what i understand this is a programming site, Please find the answer for reference below as per your question order.

1. with xCode 7.0 you can do this, we dont need any licenses and its free for any number of devices to test , refer :- [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3)
2. Yes you can generate a executable which is termed as iPA , but if you want anyone else to install the iPA, either you will have to generate this using a enterprise profile, or you wil have to add you client device id while generating the profile on apple developer protal :- refer :- [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)
   post which they can install the iPA using itunes
3. This is not possible as per my knowledge, as Apple has strict poilicies as you cant distribute witout their knowledge. that is the reason of having the apple developer account at first place.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following helps:

1) For testing on your local device XCode should set up proper provisioning files for the development builds of your app automatically once you purchase a developer license.

2) I build Enterprise Ad Hoc applications for a large publicly traded client and I'm able to send the compiled .IPA file to the client and have him test it by installing it via iTunes after I've signed it with a production certificate through XCode. He tests the app using that method before using a third party vendor to distribute the app on their corporately owned iPhones. The same should work if you sign your application with a production cert, although the aforementioned may be limited to the enterprise account's certificate.

3) If you're trying to remotely install a development version of the app on a test phone you will need to verify the phone via UDID in the Apple Developer center for AdHoc distribution, or use the TestFlight method. You can read more about how to do both of these methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

Hope this answer will help you out & good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think for that what you want you need a Paid Apple Developer because it is not possible (without Jailbreak) to install Apps which are not from the AppStore in iOS. So you have to "test" the App on each iPhone you want the App to run on, or you have to publish it to the AppStore, where you can set, that only specific Apple-IDs may download your app.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks luca4499 and Max. I guess the $99 apple dev kit is the way i'm going to have to go then.

To clarify to other users interested in the same questions.

You can develop for multiple people without using the dev kit as long as your list of people isnt changing often, or you are ok with adding each device separately.

If you want to distribute your application, the easiest way is to get the apple dev kit.